# Getting help of R function using help_console function from noamtools R package

Tags: r, github, tex, noamtools

I can get help in `R 3.1.2` on `Yates` function from `FrF2` package through:

```
?FrF2::Yates
```

Now I want to get help in `.tex` format through `help_console` function from `noamtools R` package. I tried this code but not working:

```
help_console(topic="Yates", format = "latex")
```

and

```
help_console(topic="FrF2:Yates", format = "latex")
```

The noamtools R`package can be obtained from`github` using the following commands:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("noamtools", "noamross")
library(noamtools)
```

Comment: Modify the `help_console` function so you can specify the package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is in the function `help` from the base package `utils`. You have two packages that are both exporting a function with the same name. Specifically, `DoE.base` and `FrF2` both export `Yates`, so `help` doesn't load an Rd file; instead, it wants you to choose between different files. But `help_console` doesn't know how to handle this. This can be easily corrected by adding a `package` argument to `help_console` that passes a package name down to `help`. To create achieve this in a particular R session, you can use:

```
fixInNamespace("help_console", "noamtools")
```

to load a script editor where you can change the definition of `help_console` to the following:

```
function (topic, format = c("text", "html", "latex", "Rd"), lines = NULL, 
    before = NULL, after = NULL, package = NULL) 
{
    format = match.arg(format)
    if (!is.character(topic)) 
        topic <- deparse(substitute(topic))
    helpfile = utils:::.getHelpFile(help(topic, package = (package)))
    hs <- capture.output(switch(format, text = tools:::Rd2txt(helpfile), 
        html = tools:::Rd2HTML(helpfile), latex = tools:::Rd2latex(helpfile), 
        Rd = tools:::prepare_Rd(helpfile)))
    if (!is.null(lines)) 
        hs <- hs[lines]
    hs <- c(before, hs, after)
    cat(hs, sep = "\n")
    invisible(hs)
}
```

This will then allow you to separately capture the documentation for each version of the function:

```
str(capture.output(help_console(topic="Yates", format = "latex", package="FrF2")))
## chr [1:139] "\\HeaderA{utilitiesCat}{ \\textasciitilde{}\\textasciitilde{} Internal utility functions and a user-visible constant for workin"| __truncated__ ...
str(capture.output(help_console(topic="Yates", format = "latex", package="DoE.base")))
## chr [1:65] "\\HeaderA{block.catlg3}{Catalogues for blocking full factorial 2-level and 3-level designs,  and lists of generating columns fo"| __truncated__ ...
```

In order to get this incorporated into `noamtools`, I've issued a pull request for this to be changed. You can see it [here on GitHub](https://github.com/noamross/noamtools/pull/7). It has now been merged in the main repo on GitHub, so you can install as you normally would.